# Where does Drupal store user permissions in the database?

Tags: drupal, roles

Does anyone know where Drupal stores, in the Database, the role of a user? It's not in the users table, and I can't seem to find it. I can find where it defines the role, defines the role's permissions, but I can't find where it defines what Role a certain User is. Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Drupal 6 it's in the `users_roles` table, which associates a `users` user record (via `uid`) with a `role` role record (via `rid`).

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: I think we all have those days... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The direct table it stores permissions in is `role_permission`.